# TypeError: Cannot read property 'belongsTo' of undefined

Tags: node.js, graphql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to Associations many to many, between 2 models "Trainer & Course" so I do third models "CourseTrainer" to try relation 1 to many.
but I'm getting this error:

C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\graphql-12.18.2020\graphql-12.18.2020\graphql-12.18.2020\serverapp\database\database.js:54
db.trainer.belongsTo(db.tblCourseTrainer, {
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'belongsTo' of undefined
at Object. (C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\graphql-12.18.2020\graphql-12.18.2020\graphql-12.18.2020\serverapp\database\database.js:54:14)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\graphql-12.18.2020\graphql-12.18.2020\graphql-12.18.2020\serverapp\graphql\resolvers\user.js:6:12)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)

DB Code:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = {};
const sequelize =  new Sequelize("firstDB"," "," ", {
  //from the DB amazom
  host: '  ',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    define: {
      timestamps: false,
      freezeTableName: true
    },
    operatorsAliases: false,
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000
    },
  });

  db.sequelize = sequelize
  db.Sequelize = Sequelize
  db.Sequelize = sequelize
  db.Sequelize = sequelize
  db.Sequelize = sequelize
  db.Sequelize = sequelize
  db.Sequelize = sequelize

  
  db.tblUser = require("./models/user")(sequelize, Sequelize);
  db.vewStudentCourseTrainer = require("./models/studentCourseTrainer")(sequelize, Sequelize);
  db.tblTrainer = require("./models/trainer")(sequelize, Sequelize);
  db.tblCourse = require("./models/course")(sequelize,Sequelize);
  db.tblStudent = require("./models/student")(sequelize,Sequelize);
  db.tblCourseTrainer = require("./models/courseTrainer")(sequelize, Sequelize);
  db.tblStudentCourse = require("./models/studentCourse")(sequelize, Sequelize);

  db.tblCourseTrainer.hasMany(db.tblTrainer, { as: "trainer" });
  db.trainer.belongsTo(db.tblCourseTrainer, {
    foreignKey: "intTrainerID",
    as: "trainerID",
  });

  module.exports = db
```

Models code for CourseTrainer

```
module.exports = (sequelize,DataTypes)=>{
    const CourseTrainer  = sequelize.define("tblCourseTrainer",{
      intCourseTrainerID: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },             
      intCourseID: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        foreignKey: true,
    },
    intTrainerID: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        foreignKey: true,
    },
},)
    return CourseTrainer
  }
```

Models code for Trainer

```
module.exports = (sequelize,DataTypes)=>{
    const Trainer  = sequelize.define("tblTrainer",{
      intTrainerID: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },             
      strTrainerName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    
    },)
    return Trainer
  }
```

Models code for Course

```
module.exports = (sequelize,DataTypes)=>{
    const Course  = sequelize.define("tblCourse",{
      intCourseID: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },             
      strCourseName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    },)
    return Course
  }
```

Comment: I am not familiar with `sequelize`, but what is `db.trainer` supposed to be? The error says that `db.trainer` is undefined and indeed it doesn't seem to be initialized in your code. Maybe you need to require it like you do for other fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call this:

```
db.trainer.belongsTo(...)
```

There is no `.trainer` object in the `db` object and thus `db.trainer` is `undefined` and you get the error telling you that you can't access a property `.belongsTo()` on an `undefined` value.

We can see where you declare the `db` object here:

```
const db = {};
```

And, then follow the code down to where you try to do `db.trainer.belongsTo(...)` and nowhere in there do you define `db.trainer`.  You do have this:

```
db.tblTrainer = require("./models/trainer")(sequelize, Sequelize);
```

so, perhaps you meant to be using this?

```
db.tblTrainer.belongsTo(...)
```

Comment: Thank you, it's work, but I have another question why does not show any result ?

Comment: @shaden - To look into that additional issue, please write a new question, describe what exactly you observe, what you expect to happen and what debugging steps you've taken and what you learned during that debugging.

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was that I had my `belongsTo` associations defined in different files.

The solution was to move the associations to the same file where the query was being done. For example

```
Grid.belongsToMany(Link, { through: GridLink, foreignKey: 'gridId'})
Link.belongsToMany(Grid, { through: GridLink, foreignKey: 'linkId'})

exports.listLinksInGrid = (gridId) => {
  return Grid.findOne({
    where: {
      id: gridId
    },
    include: Link
  });
};
```

instead of

```
Grid.belongsToMany(Link, { through: GridLink, foreignKey: 'gridId'})

exports.listLinksInGrid = (gridId) => {
  return Grid.findOne({
    where: {
      id: gridId
    },
    include: Link
  });
};
```

```
Link.belongsToMany(Grid, { through: GridLink, foreignKey: 'linkId'})
```